# CollapsiblePanelExtender collapses on link hover

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to use an CollapsiblePanelExtender to make some dropdown menus and am having some problems when hovering over links - can anyone help me out... 
By the way I do want to keep the AutoCollapse="True" effect.

I have the below:

```
<div  id="drop_menu2"> 

   <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder3" runat="server">

  <asp:Panel class="closePanel2" ID="Panel3" runat="server" HorizontalAlign="Left" >

  <asp:Hyperlink ID="Hyperlink1"  CssClass="test" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" title="Home" >Home</asp:Hyperlink>

   <asp:Hyperlink ID="Hyperlink2" CssClass="test" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Speach.aspx" title="Speach" >Speach</asp:Hyperlink>

      </asp:Panel>

        <!-- trigger -->
       <asp:Panel ID="trigger" runat="server">

   <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" 
   ImageUrl="~/ExpandingPanel/expand.jpg" 
   style="position: relative; top: -1px; left: 0px" 
   ToolTip="Dropdown Menu..." />
        </asp:Panel>

   </asp:PlaceHolder>

<cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender ID="CollapsiblePanelExtender2" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="Panel3"
    Collapsed="True" 
   AutoCollapse="True" 
   AutoExpand="false"

    ExpandControlID="trigger" 
    CollapsedSize="0"
    ExpandedSize="148"
    SuppressPostBack="True">

</cc1:CollapsiblePanelExtender>  


</div>
```

I have tried the following fix at:   http://forums.asp.net/t/1304389.aspx - but I think it is a bit too jerky... Any other methodes out there?

if it helps also - in source my doctype is showing as:

Thanks in advance as I can't logon to accept an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Wish I had a better suggestion for you with the CollapsiblePanel than the example you linked to, but I don't.

Since the announcement that MS is including jQuery in all future VS releases, I've mostly stopped using the Microsoft Ajax stuff for all new code and life has been significantly easier. If you're not married to the idea of using the CollapsiblePanel, this is something that jQuery easily handles via the [hover()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/hover) call.